# Split the service periods and cost monthly

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datatable

I will pull the Data-table with service periods and cost per service period from the database 

 EX:

ServiceStart   ServiceEND   Cost   Days
  1/1/2013       3/15/2013     60     74 
  3/3/2013       3/28/2013     30     26

I want to split the table such that the cost it divided according to days in the month 

 The result should look like:

ServiceStart   ServiceEND   Cost 
  1/1/2013       1/31/2013     (30*60)/74 
  2/1/2013       2/28/2013     (28*60)/74 
  3/1/2013       3/31/2013     (15*60)/74 + 30 ( as date overlaps with in month ) 
 
Is there a better way to achieve this in c# programming or using stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply math operations when selecting the data, for example:

```
SELECT ServiceStart, ServiceEND,
(DAY(EOMONTH(ServiceStart))*Cost)/Days as Cost
FROM TableName;
/* (DAY(EOMONTH(ServiceStart))*Cost) Represents the total days in the month */
```

The numbers data should of feasible datatypes like integers.

Comment: I will get random service days with cost associated with it. Dates may vary it may be 3 months 6 months or Yearly service days ( like 1/1/2013 - 11/1/2013 ) . I want to slit the cost to monthly and group with remaining overlapping service periods and cost.

Comment: Please look at my updated code and see if it helps now.

Comment: The logic you specified helps me if my service periods doesn't change in the end result. if you check my end result 3/1/2013   3/31/2013  (15*60)/74 + 30  '15' will not be equal to Day(EOMONTH(servicestart)) and my end result service periods are different form the Original Data-table service periods. Let me know if am not clear regarding this.